# Maximum $B$-field at the surface of a permanent magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, magnetic-monopoles

I have the dipole formula for a permanent spherical magnet in coordinate-free form.

$\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\frac{3(\vec{m}\cdot\hat{r})\hat{r}-\vec{m}}{r^{3}}$

I am trying to find the maximum $B$-field at the surface of the magnet, so I know I have to "maximize" the dot product which turns out to be just $mr*cos(\theta)$.  Is $\theta$ just 0 degrees in this case since the magnetic field would be strongest at the north or south poles?  Then the magnetic field would simply be $\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi}\frac{3mr\hat{r}-\vec{m}}{r^{3}}$, and if I have values for the radius of the magnet, can I put that in for r and the magnetization as m?  Unit vector $\hat{r}$ should not matter since it can be taken in any direction, although, for north or south pole it would be best to have that be $B_{z}$?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm still new to magnetism and just feeling it out for now.  I was told by a friend that the max. field strength would be at 45 degrees but this made no sense to me.

Comment: You can't use the magnetic moment field near the magnet.

Answer (score -1):

If you stay at the surface of the magnet, your $r=R$ the radius of the magnet. If you want to maximize $B$, you need to be careful, because you have a second term that isn’t aligned so you could have potential compensations.

At position $\hat r$ at azimutal angle $\theta$ from $m$, you have (projecting on $\hat r$ and its orthogonal direction) $B^2= B_0^2 (4\cos^2\theta+\sin^2 \theta)=B_0^2 (3\cos^2\theta+1)$ with $B_0=\frac{\mu_0m}{4\pi R^3}$. (Notice that the relevant quantity is not the magnetic moment or the size but the magnetization).

Luckily for you, the conclusion is still the same with the optimum angle at $\theta=0,\pi$ and maximum value $B=2B_0$.

Hope this helps and tell me if you need more precisions.